# Running hql updates without session in AR and Nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate, castle-activerecord

I am using Castle Active Record and NHibernate and need to be able to run HQL updates without using session. When I use session then it ends up causing locking issues:

```
public static ISession GetSession(out ISessionFactoryHolder factoryHolder, out bool created)
        {
            created = false;
            var type = typeof(T);
            factoryHolder = ActiveRecordMediator.GetSessionFactoryHolder();
            ISessionScope activeScope = factoryHolder.ThreadScopeInfo.GetRegisteredScope();
            ISession session = null;
            var key = factoryHolder.GetSessionFactory(type);
            if (activeScope == null)
            {
                created = true;
                session = factoryHolder.CreateSession(type);
            }
            else
            {
                if (activeScope.IsKeyKnown(key))
                    session = activeScope.GetSession(key);
                else
                    session = factoryHolder.GetSessionFactory(type).OpenSession();
            }
            return session;
        }

        public static void UpdateQuery(string query)
        {
            ISessionFactoryHolder factoryHolder;
            var created = false;
            var session = GetSession(out factoryHolder, out created);
            session.CreateQuery(query).ExecuteUpdate();
            if (created)
                factoryHolder.ReleaseSession(session);
        }
```

This is causing significant issues in our production environment due to all of the locks happening from the sessions. How would I just run hql updates without instantiating session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot execute HQL outside of an NHibernate session.  However you might find that using a stateless session will help (use a StatelessSessionScope in ActiveRecord).

Alternatively if the Stateless session is still not performant enough, you will have to execute your query using straightforward SQL, using session.CreateSqlQuery(...)